# Vertical align between div and input

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align a `div` and an `input`:

```
<div id="a">
    Button
</div>
<input type="text" id="b" placeholder="text">
```

They both share the same styles:

```
#a, #b{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-family: serif;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
}
```

However, they are not vertically aligned:

[**Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfdt6a5t/)

How is that possible?

*Please note: This is an abbreviated example from a bigger project where I have to use `vertical-align: baseline`. It is not possible to change that value and I do not want to use any hack like adding a `margin-top`. I want to understand why the vertical-align behaves this way and try to find a clean solution.*

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom;` ?

Comment: [Without explanation](http://jsfiddle.net/cfdt6a5t/3/)

Comment: I'm curious as to what you would accept as a *clean* solution. Can we stop using `inline-block` or is that a prerequisite?

Comment: I would like to keep `inline-block`

Comment: But you won't accept the obvious solution even though the original setting is inappropriate?

Comment: @suslov: You got it - that's all I needed! Thanks

Comment: @Horen: Then I guess I should post an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `height` has a static value, you can use `line-height: 30px;` CSS property to force the alignment you want.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfdt6a5t/3/)

*Cumbersome explanation:*

Your div's `baseline` is 10 px (see `line-height` property), while your element's `height` is 30 px. Text inside `input` element is vertically centered by default, `baseline`, in your case, 30px. So basically, browser tries to center elements by it's baseline, which is different for the elements, thus causing the first element, with a smaller baseline value, to be pushed down.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add **float: left** to make it align on vertically.

Comment: Agreed! Learnt something new.